# Average of a sequence of r.v.s converge to 0 a.s.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

We have $\left\{Y_{n}\right\}$ to be a sequence of independent random variables. $X_{n}$ is defined by $\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}=1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}=-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-2^{-n}\right), \mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}=2^{n}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}=-2^{n}\right)=2^{-(n+1)}$
$n=1,2, \ldots$

How can we prove:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(Y_{1}+\cdots+Y_{n}\right) \stackrel{a . s .}{\rightarrow} 0
$$

I can show $Y_n/n$ converges to 0 a.s., but I am not sure does it imply the sum is also convergent to 0 a.s.

Comment: I'm getting that $V\bigg(\frac{X_1+\dots +X_n}{n}\bigg)=\frac{2^{n+1}+2^{-n}+n-3}{n^2}$ which is very large for large $n$. Are you sure that this is true?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the conclusion is correct. but I can't find a way to prove it...

Comment: Can you show how you proved that $X_n/n$ converges almost surely to $0$? I'm getting a very large variance for $X_n/n$ as well

Comment: Using $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\left|x_{i}\right|}{i}>\frac{1}{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{-i}$

Comment: If you want to show $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely this way you would need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb P\Big(\Big|\frac{X_n}{n}\Big|>\epsilon\Big)$ converges for any fixed $\epsilon>0$

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z_k:=Y_k\mathbb{1}_{\{\lvert Y_k\rvert\leqslant 1\}}$; then $\{Y_k\neq Z_k\}$ is an event having probability $2^{-k}$ and by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, we can show that $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^n(Y_k-Z_k)$ converges to $0$ almost surely. It thus suffices to prove that $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nZ_k$ to $0$ almost surely, which is simpler than the original task, as $Z_k$ takes the values $-1$ and $1$ with probability $1/2-2^{-k-1}$ and $0$ with probability $2^{-k}$.

Nevertheless, we cannot use directly the strong law of large numbers because $(Z_k)$ is not identically distributed. Nevertheless, the fact that the $Z_k$ have bounded variance can be used in order to bound
$$
\mathbb P\left(2^{-N}\max_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 2^N}\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^nZ_k\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)
$$
thanks to Kolmogorov's maximal inequality.

Comment: Thanks for your nice work!!

Comment: Thanks for your nice work!!! But I am still confused that $2^{-N} \max _{1 \leqslant n \leqslant 2^{N}}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_{k}\right|$ will converge to 0 a.s. but not proving $n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} Z_{k}$ to 0 a.s. Also, I think $Y_n$ already has bounded variance, why we can not apply Kolmogorov's max directly?

Comment: @user98694q87 $V(Y_n)=2^n-2^{-n}+1$ which isn't bounded.